# For each regular singular point of the equation. Identify the functions p(x) and q(x).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think I´m stucked with this,
Put the given differential equation into form (3) in Section 6.3
$(x − x_0 )^2y'' + (x − x_0)p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$    (3)

for each regular singular point of the equation. Identify the functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.
$(x^2 − 1)y'' + 8(x + 1)y' + (x^2 − x)y = 0$

I think I don´t really understand what is $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.
I´ve tried doing this:

$(x^2-1)y''+ \frac{8(x+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}y'+\frac{x^2-x}{(x^2-1)}y$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2 − 1)y'' + 8(x + 1)y' + (x^2 − x)y = 0$$
First find the singular points:
$$P(x)=x^2-1=0  \implies x_0=1,-1$$
For $x_0=1$:
$$p(x)=\dfrac {8(x+1)(x-1)}{x^2-1}=8 \text { and }
\lim_{x \to 1}p(x)=8$$
$$q(x)=\dfrac {(x^2-x)(x-1)^2}{x^2-1}=\dfrac {x(x-1)^2}{x+1} \text { and }
\lim_{x \to 1}q(x)=0$$
Both  limits exist and $x_0=1$ is a regular singular point.
$$(x-1)^2y''+(x-1)p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$
$$(x-1)^2y''+8(x-1)y'+\dfrac {x(x-1)^2}{x+1}y=0$$
Now treat the case $x_0=-1$.